# join two date ranges

Tags: sql, join, impala, date-range

I have two tables like below (date format: yyyy-MM-dd). What I want is to have a history of the join between Table A and Table B based on their starttime and endtime

P.S. I forgot to clarify that the example I give below is not exhaustive. In real case, there are 3 possibilities: **(a) at time T, the hierarchy changes but not the supervisor (b) at time T, the supervisor changes but not the hierarchy (c) both changes at the same time.**

1) Table A - hierarchy

```
+--------------+------------+------------+
| hierarchy    |  startime  |  endtime   |
+--------------+------------+------------+
| Value 1      | 2017-01-01 | 2017-03-01 |
| Value 2      | 2017-03-01 | 2017-04-01 |
| Value 3      | 2017-04-01 | NULL       |
+--------------+------------+------------+
```

2) Table B - supervisor

```
+--------------+------------+------------+
|  supervisor  |  startime  |  endtime   |
+--------------+------------+------------+
| supervisor 1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-01 |
| supervisor 2 | 2017-03-01 | NULL       |
+--------------+------------+------------+
```

3) Result table

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+
| hierarchy |  supervisor  |  startime  |  endtime   |
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+
| Value 1   | supervisor 1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-01 |
| Value 1   | NULL         | 2017-02-01 | 2017-03-01 |
| Value 2   | supervisor 2 | 2017-03-01 | 2017-04-01 |
| Value 3   | supervisor 2 | 2017-04-01 | NULL       |
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

Anyone has an idea on how to do this in IMPALA/SQL??
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: select hierarchy ,supervisor  ,startime  ,endtime  from TableA a inner join TableB b on a.startime  =b.startime

Answer (score 0):

This may help  you.

```
  select a.hierarchy ,b.supervisor  ,a.startime  ,a.endtime  from TableA a inner join TableB b on a.startime  =b.startime and 
    a.endtime=b.endtime
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to clarify that sometimes (a) the hierarchy changes but not the supervisor (b) at time T, the supervisor changes but not the hierarchy (c) both changes at the same time.

Comment: did this answer helpful for  you?